# Excel VBA causing an err 0 when deleting a row

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried a number of different ways to delete a row in my Excel 2016 but I keep getting and err.number 0!

```
    ' Remove Extra Top Row
Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp 'The created rows have an extra blank line. This removes it and shifts the rest up

Err_FilterCSV:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Number
```

This throws an err 0 every time.

I even tried this

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("C1:E1").Select 'The created rows have an extra blank line. This removes it and shifts the rest up
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

And it still gives an err 0

Comment: 0 means there is no error.

Comment: You are executing the MsgBox line unconditionally after the Delete.  You need to test if there was an error first.  Post more of the code, and someone will show you how to do that

Comment: Thanks Chris. I have dozens of code snippets in this project and missed the 'Exit Sub' between the code and the error check.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete` without additional param

Comment: While this arguably cleaner code (aside from the unqualified Range reference), it's functionally no different to the OPs code, and not the cause of the issue